# Dynamically creating and updating widgets in Python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frames

I am trying to build an app where a new frame is created when a person clicks "add map". They are then prompted to upload a data file, and once a file is uploaded, they make further selections about data type, and the widgets that are presented depend on the selections that are made.

Everything is working mostly fine, except that the changes based on the selections only occur for the most recent frame (e.g. if you click "add map" for a second frame, changing the selections for the first frame no longer changes that frame's appearance).

I feel like I have to find some way to keep track of the specific widgets, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.master)
        self.configure_gui()
        self.create_widgets()
   
    def configure_gui(self):
       self.master.geometry("600x400")


    def create_widgets(self):

      self.add_map_btn = tk.Button(self.master, text="Add Map", command=self.add_map)
      self.add_map_btn.grid(row=3, column=0)
      self.map_num = 1

      self.add_map_btn = tk.Button(self.master, text="Add Map", command=self.add_map)
      self.add_map_btn.grid(row=3, column=0)
      self.map_num = 1


    def add_map(self, *args):
      ## keep track of map #
      ## create frame for Map
      self.frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.master, text="Map " + str(self.map_num))
      self.map_num += 1
      ## create button to upload data
      self.upload_data = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Upload Data", command=self.open_data_file)
      self.next_row = self.master.grid_size()[1]
      self.frame.grid(row=self.next_row, column=0, columnspan=3)
      self.upload_data.grid(row=0, column=0)

      # create radio buttons for data type
      self.data_type = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Data type: ")
      self.data_type.grid(row=1, column=0)
      self.data_type_var = tk.IntVar()
      self.numerical_radio = tk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="Numerical", variable=self.data_type_var, value=1, command=self.data_type_click)
      self.categorical_radio = tk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="Categorical", variable=self.data_type_var, value=2, command=self.data_type_click)
      self.num_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Choose statistic:")
      self.pos_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Positive Category:")
      self.neg_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Negative Category:")
      statistics = [
        "Select",
        "Mean",
        "Median",
        "Percent"]
      self.statistic = tk.StringVar()
      self.statistic.set(statistics[0])
      self.stat_drop = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, self.statistic, *statistics)


    def open_shape_file(self, *args):
      self.shape_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
      # self.city_label = tk.Label(self.master, text=self.filename)
      # self.city_label.grid(row=0, column=3)

    def open_data_file(self, *args):
      # self.data_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
      self.d = ["Yes", "No"]
      if len(self.d) > 0:
        self.numerical_radio.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.categorical_radio.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.pos_cat = tk.StringVar()
        self.neg_cat = tk.StringVar()
        self.pos_drop = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, self.pos_cat, *self.d)
        self.neg_drop = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, self.neg_cat, *self.d)

    def data_type_click(self, *args):
      if self.data_type_var.get() == 1:
        self.pos_label.grid_forget()
        self.neg_label.grid_forget()
        self.num_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.stat_drop.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.pos_drop.grid_forget()
        self.neg_drop.grid_forget()

      else:
        self.num_label.grid_forget()
        self.stat_drop.grid_forget()
        self.pos_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.neg_label.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.pos_drop.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.neg_drop.grid(row=2, column=3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = tk.Tk()
   main_app =  MainApplication(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would help if you could reduce this code down to the minimum for reproducing the problem. For example, is pandas really required to reproduce this or could you use some hard-coded dummy data?

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you for the feedback, I made some edits that should hopefully make it easier to reproduce.

Comment: You still have a dependency on padas, which doesn't seem at all related to the question being asked.